# Javascript/HTML: Format Positioning for a Bar Graph

Tags: javascript, html, graph, formatting

[image]

As shown, my bar graph tends to appear at the upper portion of the my page. I want it to appear at the bottom so I can place the title of my project above the bar graphs. I am not sure about the proper syntax for javascript. Here's the code for my bar graph..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title> Project Blue Summary </title>
</head>


<body>
  <div id="bar-example"></div>

<script>
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    { y: 'SM Mall of Asia', a: 500, b: 390 },
    { y: 'SM Megamall', a: 750,  b: 650 },
    { y: 'SM North Edsa', a: 350,  b: 240 },
    { y: 'SM Aura', a: 700,  b: 250 },
    { y: 'Robinson\'s Manila', a: 150,  b: 340 },
    { y: 'Robinson\'s Cebu', a: 725,  b: 625 },
     { y: 'Ayala Cebu', a: 100, b: 400 },
    { y: 'Rockwell', a: 135,  b: 235 },
    { y: 'Serendra', a: 200,  b: 815 },
    { y: 'Bel-Air', a: 750,  b: 550 },
    { y: 'Festival Mall', a: 450,  b: 120 },
    { y: 'Adriatico', a: 250,  b: 90 },
    { y: 'UP Twon Center', a: 120, b: 490 },
    { y: 'Greenhills', a: 500, b: 270 },
    { y: 'Glorietta/Greenbelt', a: 600, b: 450 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['AMEX', 'With BDO Terminal']
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right you might use something like this:

```
    var bar = document.getElementById('bar-example');
    var w = window.innerWidth
    || document.documentElement.clientWidth
    || document.body.clientWidth;

    var h = window.innerHeight
    || document.documentElement.clientHeight
    || document.body.clientHeight;

    console.log(w+" "+h);

    bar.style.width = w+"px";
    bar.style.height = h+"px";
```

Other solution if you are using JQuery

```
    var bar = $('#bar-example');
    var wi = $(document).width();
    var he = $(document).height();
    bar.css({'width':wi, 'height':he});
```

or one line way

```
$('#bar-example').css({'width':$(document).width(), 'height':$(document).height()});
```

if these are not gonna work for you please let me know :)